# How do you create roles and policies with Boto 3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, boto3

How can I create roles and policies with Boto 3? I've read the [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#assumerolepolicy), but still cannot work out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`IAM.Client.create_policy`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_policy) and [`IAM.Client.create_role`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_role). The examples from the docs to create a policy and a role, respectively:

```
response = client.create_policy(
    PolicyName='string',
    Path='string',
    PolicyDocument='string',
    Description='string'
)
```

and

```
response = client.create_role(
    Path='string',
    RoleName='string',
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument='string'
)
```

If you've tried these and they don't work, please elaborate on what, exactly, you've tried.